# AngularJS : Why ng-show is not working on IE11?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, angularjs-directive

In my code ng-show is working fine on firefox and not on IE 11.

```
<div ng-show="isExist" class="panel panel-default">
```

and in controller

```
$scope.isExist = false;

if(user.name)
{
   $scope.isExist = true;

}
```

I am getting $scope.isExist as false and the Div gets hide on ff/chrome, but not on ie11.

Comment: did you do any debugging to confirm `user.name` and `$scope.isExists` is what you expect it to be in all three browsers? (that needs to be included in your question)

Comment: did you checked out for errors in IE Developer Tools? user.name has the right value?

Comment: @KevinB , i have debugged on all three browsers and i got the final value for $scope.isExist as false. But IE11 behaves differently when use ng-show.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Yes, i have debugged with IE browser's dev tool and getting as false for isExist as like other browser dev tools value. The div gets hided on FF or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a CSS question. ng-show will add .ng-hide  class to the element. Double check your panel and panel-default classes to make sure that nothing is overriding the style.

Or remove your panel and panel-default classes and it will work.

Comment: ng-show is a directive, this is not related with css. The problem is the value for isExist

Comment: from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow  :The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute. The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the .ng-hide CSS class onto the element.

Comment: this may be possible because for me also ng-hide class is getting apply on ng-hide condition but may be due to some parent class it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. It behaves weired. Now it started working fine. I am pretty sure it is not a cache issue since i have cleared number of times. not sure what went wrong. it works fine now. thanks for your help.

Comment: because IE11 sucks

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue of `ng-show` not working in Internet Explorer.

The [official ngShow AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) mentions about this, and provides a few workarounds for this.

(I'll copy-paste the text mentioned in that link, in case that link has expired or is not working for some reason)

> When using `ngShow` and / or `ngHide` to toggle between elements, it
> can happen that both the element to show and the element to hide are
> visible for a very short time.
>
> This usually happens when the `ngAnimate` module is included, but no
> actual animations are defined for `ngShow` / `ngHide`. Internet
> Explorer is affected more often than other browsers.
>
> There are several way to mitigate this problem:
>
> - Disable animations on the affected elements.
> - Use `ngIf` or `ngSwitch` instead of `ngShow` / `ngHide`.
> - Use the special CSS selector `ng-hide.ng-hide-animate` to set `{display: none}` or similar on the affected elements.
> - Use `ng-class="{'ng-hide': expression}` instead of instead of `ngShow` / `ngHide`.
> - Define an animation on the affected elements.

The second suggestion (replacing `ng-show` with `ng-if`) worked for me. So in your case, you could consider using this -

```html
<div ng-if="isExist" class="panel panel-default">
```